# Convert XML to Base64 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, base64, data-conversion

In my code I have converted data from a JSON Model into XML. To ensure correct formatting I parse my created XML string into XML Doc. (API cannot work with XML that is not well formatted)

Therefore, I need some help converting my XML Doc variable into Base64 (instead of my XML string) using Javascript.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlDataString,"text/xml");
```

Does anyone know a function **besides btoa()** which is used for converting strings?

Using btoa(xmlDataString) returns API error "Xml parsing error: not well formed" and using btoa(xmlDoc) returns Base64 which returns when decoded again: "[object XMLDocument]"

Thanks

Comment: Why use anything else than btoa()?

Comment: As far as I know btoa() is only used for strings. However, I have a parsed XML variable. Of course I tried this, the result does not seem to fit the result of external encoders.

Comment: @jaku_: how does the result from external encoders differ from your results?  (I'd even recommend adding this bit of information to your question - it seems like a very useful detail)

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. Hope this helps

Comment: Serialize your XML and then convert to Base64: `(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml);`

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your XML and then convert to Base64: (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml);

```
prolog = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
XmlStr = prolog + "<bookz/>";
var xmlz  = parser.parseFromString(XmlStr, "application/xml");
console.log(window.btoa((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlz)));
```

Result:

`PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/Pgo8Ym9va3ovPg==`

Comment: Thanks for the input! The API still throws the error "Xml parsing error: not well formed" when calling it with the result.

Comment: You need to check the api specs for the format to send a request. Try to add that to your post.